# Python, наследование классов

Tags: python, наследование

**Привет, стак.**
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу грамотно раскидать классы по отдельным .py файлам. По условию лабораторной необходимо создать несколько классов по принципу наследования, и одно из требований - каждый класс в отдельном файле. Также в основном классе необходимо создать метод, который будет создавать экземпляр дочернего класса, не могу догнать как верно это всё реализовать.

С импортом там вообще беда была, по итогу всё импортировало друг друга.
Ошибки были по типу: "Имя не обнаружено" и "Невозможно импортировать"

Вот условие, в общем.

> Написать программу, в которой описана иерархия классов:
> функция от одной переменной (арктангенс, арккотангенс, а
> также класс, необходимый для представления производных).
> Базовый класс должен иметь методы получения значения
> функции для данного значения переменной, а также создания
> экземпляра класса, представляющего собой производную
> текущего экземпляра. Продемонстрировать работу всех
> методов классов всех классов.

```
first.py 
class A(): # базовый класс
   def __init__(self, param1, param2):
      ...
   def method_A(self):
      obj_B = B(param1, param2)  # Создание экземпляра дочернего класса.
      return obj_B

second.py
class B(A): # арктангенс
   ...

third.py
class C(A): # арккотангенс
   ...

fourth.py
class D(): # Вообще это класс для производной, но не знаю от чего его наследовать.
   ...
```

Comment: А запускаться программа должна через один файл, или любой файл должен запускаться независимо? Если один, то какой?

Comment: Либо в отдельном файле main.py, либо в том же, где находится родительский класс A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так, думаю:
**a.py**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._dict = {
            'B': B,
            'C': C,
        }
        self.childs = []
        self.param = param
        
    def create_child(self, child, parameter):
        self.childs.append(self._dict[child](parameter))
        return self.childs[-1]

    def get_child_var(self, child, var):
        return child.__dict__.get(var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from b import B
    from c import C
```

**b.py**

```
from a import A

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, degree):
        self.degree = degree

    def print(self):
        print(self.degree)
```

**c.py**

```
from a import A

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, degree):
        self.degree = degree

    def print(self):
        print(self.degree)
```

и т.д.

Примеры вызовов:

```
a = A(10)
c = a.create_child('C', 5)
a.get_child_var(c, 'degree')
```

Answer (score 0):

Работает, если запускать first.py

## first.py

```
import second


class A:  # базовый класс
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2

    def method_A(self):
        obj_B = second.B(
            self.param1, self.param2
        )  # Создание экземпляра дочернего класса.
        return obj_B


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import third

    a = A(1, 2)
    print("A", a)
    b = second.B(1, 2)
    print("B", b)
    c = third.C(1, 2)
    print("C", c)
```

## second.py

```
from first import A


class B(A):  # арктангенс
    ...
```

## third.py

```
from first import A


class C(A):  # арккотангенс
    ...
```